# only half value of string is set to the key in Json_setValue() function

Tags: c, json

When i am passing a value in `Json_setValue(h, key, value, valueSize)` function then only half of the string value is set.
After building the object in string form using:

```
Json_build(object,cpy_buff,&builtBuffSize);
```

the buffer contains only half of the string in data key(key2).
I am using this library:

- [Texas Instruments — Network Services APIs — JSON Parser/Builder](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/simplelink_msp432e4_sdk_2_10_00_17/docs/ns/html/group__ti__utils__json__JSON.html)
- Function [Json_createTemplate](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/simplelink_msp432e4_sdk_2_10_00_17/docs/ns/html/group__ti__utils__json__JSON.html#ga7163bc0f4e11452b95ef2522e0a4351b)

My code:

```
   while((ftell(new))<=(fsize-88))
   {
       for(i=1;i<3;i++)
       {
         fgets(cpy_buff,sizeof(cpy_buff),new);
         strcat(mybuff,cpy_buff);
         memset(cpy_buff, 0, sizeof(cpy_buff));
        // puts("yes");
       }

       x=strlen(mybuff);
       sprintf(conbuff,"len of my buff %d",x);
       puts(conbuff);
  //     puts(mybuff);                    //1

       sprintf(conbuff,"pointer loc=%d",ftell(new));
 //      puts(conbuff);

       Json_parse(object, mybuff, strlen(mybuff));
       sprintf(conbuff,"pos of new after reading buff  =%d",ftell(new));
       puts(conbuff);                           //2
       Json_getValue(object, key1, &o_value1, &value1_size);                 // get value of line key in output value buff
       Json_getValue(object, key2, &o_value2, &value2_size);             //get value of data key in output value buff

////   o_value2 is the data buffer.This is will be used to publish data

       Json_setValue(object,key1,&s_value,value1_size);
       strcpy(newbuff,o_value2);
       puts(newbuff);
       Json_setValue(object,key2,&newbuff,value2_size);
```

Now after building the object again the cpy
-buff only contains (Jan 1 2017 00:00:00 75 822 96) instead of (Jan 1 2017 00:00:00 75 822 96 548 85 76 82 93 78 82 64 89 899)

```
       // only half string is present in the cpy_buff////////////////////////////////////////
       Json_build(object,cpy_buff,&builtBuffSize);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       puts(cpy_buff);


       sprintf(conbuff,"pos of new before writing into file =%d",ftell(new));
       puts(conbuff);                                           //3

       fseek(new, -x, SEEK_CUR);
       sprintf(conbuff,"pos of new after setting to -x  =%d",ftell(new));
       puts(conbuff);


       fwrite(cpy_buff,1,strlen(cpy_buff),new);
       fputs("\r\n",new);

       sprintf(conbuff,"pos of new after writing into file =%d",ftell(new));
       puts(conbuff);

       fseek(new,0, SEEK_CUR);
       sprintf(conbuff,"pos of new after setting to 0  =%d",ftell(new));
       puts(conbuff);
       memset(mybuff, 0, sizeof(mybuff));


    }


 fclose(new);

    /* Close both inputfile[] and outputfile[] */
 strcpy(conbuff,"akjsdabsdas");
 puts(conbuff);


    /* Stopping the SDCard */
    SDFatFS_close(sdfatfsHandle);
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Drive %u unmounted\n", DRIVE_NUM);


    return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to read the code - can you simplify the code to show just the problem piece, preferably using constants and not reading from some file, so that anyone who wanted to reproduce could do so?

Comment: This is fairly closely related to a previous question [`fgets()` does not read data which is stored in JSON format in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721920/fgets-does-not-read-data-which-is-stored-in-json-format-in-text-file) by the same OP.  I think this manages to be a different question.

Comment: You should replace calls such as `puts(conbuff)` with a statement such as `printf("conbuff = [[%s]]\n", conbuff);` because that notation shows more clearly trailing blanks and exposes embedded CR characters, etc.  You should also show the output from such debugging statements from a run of your program (the code you show in the question) on your sample data file.  You should also include the sample data file in the question, presented in an unambiguous format (present it as code — copy/paste and then indent by selecting it and using the **`{}`** button above the text box).

Comment: Or make the data unambiguous by making it into a string initializer for a character array.

Comment: The chances are very high that your I/O code is confusing the JSON library somehow.  However, it is not clear what data you're reading, so it is extremely hard for us to guess what is going wrong.  You need to work harder on making an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
What you've provided doesn't look minimal.

Comment: The commentary in the middle may be confusing what might otherwise be a cohesive function. It isn't clear what it is documenting.  Leave the code in a continuous sequence; remove as many comments as you can.  Show the output from the diagnostics in a separate block of text after the code.